# Cell Broadcast Function Disappeared on Samsung Galaxy S4 Android 5.1

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, 5.1-lollipop

Cell Broadcast messages function which is usually here : **messages** -> **setting** -> **cb messages** seems to have disappeared on new Samsung phones.

I have Samsung Galaxy S4 Android 5.1.

Maybe this function is hidden in some other place?

Comment: Try here : Press the Menu key -> Press Settings -> Cell Broadcast Activation.

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't joined the site after the question has been migrated, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

Lollipop 5.1. There's an app called "Emergency Alerts"
Launch it. 
Click upper right pop up menu and select "settings" to customize.